# DrupalSettings are not passing the values from block to js?

Tags: 8, javascript, blocks

I have been trying to pass the variables from block to jquery.

In Block.php,

```
return [
      '#theme' => 'block--exampleblock',
      '#value' => 'test',
      '#attached' => [
        'drupalSettings' => [
          'example' => [
            'data' => $data,
            'color'=> $color,
          ],
        ],
        'library' => [
          'example/examplejs',
        ],
      ],
    ];
```

and I used the data and color values in js

```
drupalSettings.example.data; 
drupalSettings.example.color;
```

and belows are added the dependency in the library

```
dependencies:
    - core/jquery
    - core/drupal
    - core/drupalSettings
```

After uninstalled and installed the modules, The variables have been passing from block to js.

But After clearing cache or sometimes Its not working.

Its showing an issue like

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
    at Object.attach (charts.js?v=1.x:10)
    at drupal.js?v=8.6.16:25
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Object.Drupal.attachBehaviors (drupal.js?v=8.6.16:22)
    at drupal.init.js?v=8.6.16:16
    at HTMLDocument.t (ready.min.js?v=1.0.8:4)
```

I am not able to fix this issue.

Can anyone help to solve this?

Comment: You didn't show us the code that is throwing the error.

Comment: I added the issue in the query

Comment: I don't see it.

Comment: drupalSettings.example.data; here in js. Its showing an error.

Answer (score 2):

99 % sure it is the way your js file is set. as the above should work. for a test please do this:

```
(function ($, Drupal, drupalSettings) {
  'use strict';
  Drupal.behaviors.testStuff = {
    attach: function (context) {
        alert('yes i am attached');
        console.log(drupalSettings);
        if (drupalSettings.example) {
           console.log(drupalSettings.example);
        }
    }
  };
})(jQuery, Drupal, drupalSettings);
```

if you don't see that in the log then try this ...

```
$build = [];
$build['stuff'] = [
  '#theme' => 'block--exampleblock',
  '#value' => 'test',
];
$build['#attached']['drupalSettings']['example'] =  [
        'data' => $data,
        'color'=> $color,
];
$build['#attached']['library'][] = 'example/examplejs';
return $build;
```

remember to clear your cache too.

Comment: Its tried this i have replaced the stuff to some other thing. But Its not working. alert, first console is working, and second console is showing undefined.

Comment: @logesh – Sounds a bit like a caching problem. Maybe try disabling cache for this single block. Or have it cached with a certain context (user, URL, or whatever your block/JS is supposed to do).

Comment: @leymannx, I added the max age as zero, and uncommented $settings['cache']['bins']['dynamic_page_cache'] = 'cache.backend.null'; settings.local.php. It is not working

Comment: @leymannx, I am getting an error in drupal.js in my local. Is that causing an issue. I am still not able to figure out the issue.

Comment: @logesh – What error? If it's unrelated to your JS you need to fix that error first. An error in one script may also cause other JS to fail.